# Give user empty form on form validation error

Tags: forms

I'm using braintree.js with a custom form.  For those not familiar, braintree.js does client side encryption of the form fields before submission to the server.  On my end I get a bunch of gibberish (this is expected).  If a form validation error occurs, I want the form displayed again alerting the user of the error but I don't want any of the fields pre-populated because the pre-populated values are now the client side encrypted gibberish.  Is there a method of doing this in the _validate function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to unset the value from within the form validation function. In my case the element is named `foo` and it only validates if it's set to `bar`:

```
function mymodule_myform_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['input']['foo'] != 'bar') {
    unset($form_state['complete form']['foo']['#value']);
    form_error($form['foo'], 'foo is not equal to bar');
  }
}
```

If the user enters anything but `bar` in `foo`, we set a form error and they presented with the form again without anything in the `foo` field.

I'm not sure how/if the form state array is affected by, for example, the i18n or locale modules, but this should get you started.

Comment: This, whether it is correct or not, indeed gives me the results I want.